# Xcode 7 Cast from XCUIElement to unrelated type 'String' always fails while fetching JSON

Tags: swift

I am trying to fetch the values from JSON array and i am getting an error "Cast from 'XCUIElement!' to unrelated String always fails."

I am using Xcode 7 with iOS 9.1.

My code is as below:

```
        let url = NSURL(string: urlAsString)!
        let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()


        let jsonQuery = urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }

            do {
                let jsonResult = (try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSMutableArray
                //     print (jsonResult)


                for usernames in jsonResult {
                    let influencer_username = usernames["influencer_username"] as! String


                    print("influencer_username: \(influencer_username)")
                }
```

Answer (score 10):

With Xcode 7.1.1 Not fixed but this workaround helped me:

`let influencer_username = usernames["influencer_username"] as AnyObject as! String`

Comment: This also worked around my problem -- but I have absolutely no idea why ...  It doesn't make even a little bit of sense to me ...

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve this issue by removing the "themostplayedTests" from my Target Membership.

Comment: XCUIElement is used for test target. How this error is resolved, without removing the test target ?

Comment: yep, I did the same thing. I have removed it from the test target and the problem is resolved. I wasn't doing unit testing anyway.

Comment: If you remove the class from the target then you cannot perform tests. So this is not a solution, this is just a workaround to avoid warnings.

Comment: @MatterGoal: But as other posts say that `XCUIElement` is required only with the test target which is not required by default, right.